# Cannot get dompdf to work

Tags: files

I have extracted the dompdf libraries folder to `/sites/all/libraries`

Re: 2. Edit `dompdf_config.inc.php` to fit your installation.

What exact changes do I need to make to this file???

Also, I am getting this warning in the drupal admin:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in print_pdf_settings() (line 22 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/print/print_pdf/print_pdf.admin.inc).

Comment: Which module are you trying to use?  This should probably be reported to that module's issue queue, not here.

Comment: @PatrickKenny OP is referring to the [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module, as shown in the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print module works best when you copy the library `dompdf` (or `tcpdf`) to the module folder directly. In this was you don't need to edit the file, and the print module will detect the library automatically.

- Extract the `dompdf` directory into `sites/all/modules/print` so that you have `dompdf_config.inc` at `sites/all/modules/print/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc`.
- Ensure that you have write access to `PUBLIC/print_pdf/dompdf/fonts` directory.
- Your print module should now show the detection of the library at `admin/config/user-interface/print/pdf`.
  [image: snapshot]
- You should now be able to export the nodes to PDF :)